# How to change a .p12 file to .key file

Tags: ssl, private-key

I have a `.p12` file, I can also transfer it to a `.pem` file, but how to transfer it as a `.key` file?

Answer (score 51):

`openssl pkcs12 -in out.p12 -nodes -out private.key -nocerts`

openssl will ask you for a password, then store the unencrypted private key into the file `private.key`

Documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/pkcs12.html

Answer (score 0):

openssl pkcs12 -info -in INFILE.p12 -nodes

**You will then be prompted for the PKCS#12 file’s password:**

Enter Import Password: